# Android Studio Build error with AppCompat library newbie q

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

I couldn't find a thread exclusive to studio so I apologize if this is a dup. I am new to android studio and have a basic problem. I have all the most recent support libraries installed. I am attempting to use the AppCompat library but it is giving me an error on this line of the styles.xml file.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

The errors are as follows:

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':FeedBackUser:processDebugResources'.
> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task      ':FeedBackUser:processDebugResources'
```

This is the gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {

// You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
// The Support Repository (separate from the corresponding library) can be found in the Extras category.
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'

// You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
// The Support Repository (separate from the corresponding library) can be found in the Extras category.
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:0.0.+'
```

}

The support v4 is fine, and it shows up in my external libraries area of android studio. AppCompat does not. It is definitely installed as it is located in the directory it installs into with the other support libraries. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change dependencies to next:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
}
```

Comment: That worked but I have no idea why? What is the difference between the way it was notated and the present version?

Comment: The old version for appcompact was **0.0.+** but it should be **18.0.+**